# Download Whatsapp Business Media Image API

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I am Using Whatsapp Media API to get Image send from user to business number using webhooks and I also get the Image ID and URL and Image as well in Postman but when I use that curl request made from Postman it always shows Facebook error:

> **Sorry, something went wrong.
> We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can.**

But its working fine in Postman what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ 
Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'Image_URL_from_Api',
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $ua,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer My_Token'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: What is "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,`your text`"??? That `your text` should not be there.

Comment: The endpoint is likely going to be `https` yet the only option in your curl config is set to not verify the peer ( which is not a good idea ) - you should probably have a more fully featured set of options to negotiate correctly with the SSL endpoint

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius that must be added when I was writing the problem here it wasn't in my code. And secondly, even if I remove not verify SSL the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got the answer I needed to give the user_agent value which is in postman it is automatically putting CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.10' in the header but for curl, I've added CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'curl/7.64.1', and it worked.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent