# Cannot Download Media from WhatsApp Business API - Working with Postman and cURL - Not working with NodeJS Fetch

Tags: node.js, facebook, curl, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm having issues trying to download media files from the WhatsApp Business API. Following along with their documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#download-media) they provide a cURL command that is successful in downloading a media file when used - however, the same request (I think) when done using NodeJS' fetch returns `text/html` responses with vague error wording and a 200 status code.

```bash
# Successful cURL:
curl "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=281274211304477&ext=1705672414&hash=ATtH6AOGFu0RqEpENicHUg8HCUkVfwGzfrHVCdiE7J8AUA" --header "Authorization: Bearer ..."
```

```js
// Successful cURL from child_process.exec:
exec(
  `curl --location "${mediaURL}" --header "Authorization: Bearer ..."`
);
```

```js
// Unsuccessful fetch:
fetch(
  "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=281274211304477&ext=1705672414&hash=ATtH6AOGFu0RqEpENicHUg8HCUkVfwGzfrHVCdiE7J8AUA",
  { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer ..." } }
);
```

Suggestion from [WhatsApp Cloud API Receiving Images from Users Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214351/whatsapp-cloud-api-receiving-images-from-users-error) is also unsuccessful, unfortunately:

```js
// Also unsuccessful fetch:
fetch("https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=281274211304477&ext=1705672414&hash=ATtH6AOGFu0RqEpENicHUg8HCUkVfwGzfrHVCdiE7J8AUA", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer ...",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.64.1",
  },
})
```

Note: The `lookaside.fbsbx.com` URLs are all retrieved successfully from the WhatsApp Business APIs.

Per the documentation, a 404 error should occur if the link has expired, however, this isn't the case - and the access token hasn't expired either. Looking through the Community Forums, specifically https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1367000994138329/?join_id=f25971b6b4f9cc4, many conversations suggest that the `User-Agent` header should be spoofed - yet this doesn't seem to work either, although tweaking the `User-Agent` header within Postman yields varying results.

**Successful in Postman:**

[image: Successful Postman Result]

**Unsuccessful when `User-Agent` is adjusted in Postman:**

[image: Unsuccessful Postman Result with Real User-Agent]

**Unsuccessful when `User-Agent` is removed in Postman:**

[image: Unsuccessful Postman Result with no User-Agent]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I was unable to use the Meta for Developers' "Report a bug" forms as support appears to be unavailable for WhatsApp Business APIs.

Also seen posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897702/whatsapp-cloud-api-can-not-retrieve-media-file?rq=2), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638168/download-whatsapp-business-media-image-api?rq=2) on StackOverflow; [1](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/3106314033016574/), [2](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1367000994138329/?join_id=f25971b6b4f9cc4), [3](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/334210742781485/), [4](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/561255015732358/), [5](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/407858358063626/), [6](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/794303931888357/) on Meta Support Forums.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WhatsApp Cloud API Receiving Images from Users Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214351/whatsapp-cloud-api-receiving-images-from-users-error)

Comment: Unfortunately not, still got `text/html` returned with a `200` status code. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was swapping the fetch library. Swapping NodeJS native `fetch` for `axios` or using a ponyfill such as `cross-fetch` and setting the `User-Agent` header to "`node`";

When using `cross-fetch`, the following fetch worked:

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch";

fetch("https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/...", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer ...",
    "User-Agent": "node",
  },
})
```

Note: There is a very similar snippet in the original question, whilst the `User-Agent` has changed the fetch appeared to work with the same value too.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue.

Using User-Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)` seems to work for me.